# QNetworkReply crushes program in DEBUG mode with an error in ntdll.dll

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple program on Qt. It works fine when compiled in RELEASE mode, but crushes in DEBUG mode. The bug reproduces only under Windows, under Linux works fine. 
I've tested so far:

1. MSVC 2015 x32 Qt5.9.6
2. MSVC 2015 x32 Qt.5.11.3
3. MinGW x32 Qt.5.9.6

The problem occurs in file ntdll.dll

Here is the content of main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtNetwork>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Hello buddy from program start";
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://qt.io/"));
    QPointer<QNetworkAccessManager> manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QPointer<QNetworkReply> reply = manager->get(request);
    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &a, &QCoreApplication::quit);
    int result = a.exec();
    qDebug() << "Goodbye buddy";
    return result;
}
```

And *.pro file.

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT +=  network widgets
CONFIG += c++14 network
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

And here is the program output.

```
int __cdecl main(int,char *[]) Hello buddy from program start
Goodbye buddy
```

That means that program successfully reaches the end of `main` function and crushes afterwards.

Any ideas? Is that a well-known bug?

UPDATE

I've removed redundant include's, added QPointer's and the program output.

Comment: Change the pointers to explicit `QPointer`, e.g. `QPointer<QNetworkAccessManager> manager = ...`. It's possible that you're deleting dangling pointers, i.e. also known as double deletion. Using a `QPointer` will prevent that. It's likely that deleting the `QNetworkManager` will collect the reply safely and automatically, and thus there's no need to delete it explicitly.

Comment: Also, your header includes are excessive: all you need to include is `#include <QtNetwork>`. Literally, just that one line. Don't include the other files manually unless they are relevant to the example. Also, don't include via `<QtModule/QClass>`: include `<QClass>` directly. If the compiler complains about missing include file, you must ensure that the project file contains `QT += module`, then re-run qmake or wipe the build folder: your project is misconfigured and doesn't include the `QtModule`. The compiler is telling you early of that.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've removed redundant include's and changed `auto` to `QPointer` but the program still crushes.

Comment: This looks like a Qt bug. Quite possibly a long-standing one. One problem I see is that you're leaking `QNetworkAccessManager`.

Comment: I'll try to post it on https://bugreports.qt.io. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QObject::deleteLater()` instead of delete.

Comment: `QObject::deleteLater()` will schedule the deletion of an object to a moment when control returns to the event loop. But there is no running event loop anymore thus the deletion never happens.